# Log a message that changes in rust?

Tags: logging, rust, docker-compose, progress-bar

I'm trying to log a message that can change with variables.

What I mean:

- print message with vars a, b
- remove message
- print it again with different values for a, b

Now, it's not exactly a progress bar so I can't use something like inidcatif.

I've tried using this:

```rust
let message = format!(
    "\x1B[2K\rA: {}, B: {}",
    a, b
);

print!("{}", message);
std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
```

This just prints the line a bunch of times and doesn't change the line.

This is a docker-compose log

Comment: In which terminal do you see this problem? I have tried your code and every line is cleared and overwritten by the following message.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that. It's a Docker compose log

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add crucial information instead of hiding that info in comments.

Comment: I did, it just didn't submit it, so it didn't get approved...? I don't know how this platform works tbh

Answer (score 1):

Does your terminal actually support ANSI escape codes? Because it works fine for me:

```rust
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    for (a, b) in std::iter::zip(0.., &["A", "B", "C", "D"]) {
        let message = format!("\x1B[2K\rA: {}, B: {}", a, b);

        print!("{}", message);
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1))
    }
}
```

does show the line changing over time.

Incidentally the `format!` is unnecessary, you can format everything in `print!` directly

```rust
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    for (a, b) in std::iter::zip(0.., &["A", "B", "C", "D"]) {
        print!("\x1B[2K\rA: {a}, B: {b}");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1))
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention it, it's a Docker (compose) log.